# extract key value from json python

Tags: json, angularjs, python-2.7, parsing

I want help to extract "url" value from - https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/channels/1640/courses?is_angular_app=true&p=2

```
import urllib2, json
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/channels/1640/courses?is_angular_app=true&p=2')
data = json.load(response)

for data["url"] in data.items():
    print data["url"]
```

It doesn't work above . Please help

Comment: Check this: response returns a JSON dictionary, no array, neither a property 'url' - however, the response contains the property 'result' which stores an array of course objects that have a url property. So, you might iterate on the results property instead on the entire response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code you can get url of first array

```
import urllib2, json
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/channels/1640/courses?is_angular_app=true&p=2')
data = json.load(response)

print data['results'][0]['url']
```

Use for loop for getting all url from every array

```
import urllib2, json
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/channels/1640/courses?is_angular_app=true&p=2')
data = json.load(response)

i = 0;
for data["url"] in data['results']:
    print data['results'][i]['url']
    i+=1
```

Comment: I did this - 

for each in data['results']:
    print each['url']

Comment: Thanks Paresh . I will go ahead & accept your answer ,it helped me to get idea to iterate 'results' array .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import urllib2, json
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/channels/1640/courses?is_angular_app=true&p=2')
data = json.load(response)
for i in range(len(data['results'])):
   print data['results'][i]['url']
```